# Drawing balls with replacement, until I have one of each.

Tags: combinatorics

A urn has (n+1) types of balls, n of unique colors and the rest black. When picking a ball randomly from the urn, a colored (non black) ball has a probability of p of being picked. Each ball of color has equal probability of being picked, ie each has a (p/n) chance of being picked. The urn has infinite balls/we are picking with replacement.

Let X be the number of picks until we get at least 1 of each n colored balls.

What is the Expected value of X ? What is the probability distribution of X ?

Comment: Should each colored ball have $\frac{1-p}{n}$ chance of being picked?

Comment: Black balls have a (1-p) chance of getting picked, balls of a certain non-black color have a (p/n) chance, since there are n colors.

Comment: I must have read this too quickly. I see now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  you have to pick $\frac 1{p}$ balls to get a colored one, so multiply that by the solution to the [Coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)

Comment: I believe the number of picks required to get a colored ball is (1/p), otherwise thanks, this is the answer I am looking for. The final answer is (1/p) * n * Harmonic_sum(n).

Comment: @SidDatta:  I got backwards, you are right.  Fixed.